# Should question titles use "I" or "you"?

Tags: discussion, asking

I have noticed questions on Arqade phrases in different ways.

Which of the following ways is better, does it not matter, or does it depend on the circumstances?

1. Can I negate the effects of a slime block?
   vs.
   Can you negate the effects of a slime block?
2. If I die, will I lose all my items?
   vs.
   If you die, will you lose all your items?

Which is the best way to put your question title, or does it matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really doesn't matter. If we can understand what you are trying to ask, whatever pronouns you choose to use for the speaker (yourself) are fine. People tend to default to "you" vs "I" because second person makes it feel possibly more approachable to others but it's not really a necessity. We mostly just want well written questions that allow us to help and give good quality answers. There isn't any sort of style guide or "proper" way to do that.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering.

Comment: You is second person, surely?